# How much space is needed to reclaim space from a table in MyISAM

Tags: mariadb, myisam

MariaDB 10.x | MyISAM

My question is very similar to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83380/how-much-space-is-needed-to-reclaim-space-from-a-table-in-innodb) one but regarding MyISAM.

I have a DB server that's running very low on disk space (2.5 GB free) and a MyISAM database with individual tables that are 3 GB and 8 GB in size.  I've successfully deleted entries from the tables so I'm confident that *some* of the space is white space but I'm not sure how much.

I've heard conflicting statements from folks regarding what happens when running `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  Some people say it doesn't require any extra disk space... others tell me it will create a new table and copy individual rows into the new table... and only AFTER that's complete will it begin reclaiming disk space.

Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) is not very clear on the subject.

From my experience, I'd say it always rebuilds fresh table files for data and index.

Intuitively, from what I know about MyISAM storage engine, I'd say it should be possible to run a full data file *in place* optimisation if and only if the rows have constant length. That is if you don't use columns with dynamic lengths (`VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, etc.).

Regarding index file, rebalancing the trees might be possible *in place*, but at a higher cost (duration).